# Turn Oracle DECODE statement into SQL CASE statement

Tags: sql, oracle11g, decode

I am pretty good at SQL but I can't figure out this DECODE nest statement.  I'm trying to figure a way to CASE this long, nested DECODE statement.

I am CASE WHEN on each of them where it says DECODE or not sure what's happening.  I read about Oracle DECODE and this is so nested I can't seem to get a grip on it.   Thanks experts.

```
select decode(decode(table1.field1,'I',decode(table2.field2,table2.field3,'Y','N'),'T',
decode(table1.field1,table1.field12,'Y','N')),'N',
decode(decode(table1.field3,table4.field13,'Y', 'N') || table5.field1,'YY','Y','N'),
decode(table3.field1,'I',decode(table1.field6,table8.field1,'Y','N'),'T',
decode(table2.field3,table1.field1,'Y','N'))) as FieldName
```

Comment: Start with the innermost call.  Do you understand what it does? Can you convert just it?

Comment: I hope it's just a coursework and not a part of a real-life code.

Comment: haha no, it's query that Business Objects wrote I believe...I am trying to get it out of Oracle into SQL Case and it's a mess trying to understand it.

Comment: I understand what it does just not the nested stuff.  It's decode within decode it looks like and it's confusing.  I may have to dissect it one statement by one statement to get it to parse.

Comment: Yes, go `decode` by `decode` from inside out.  When you done, consider posting it here as your own answer.

Comment: Will do thanks much.